# Returning null where values don't exist in SQLAlchemy (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I've got 3 tables

- tblOffers (tsin, offerId)
- tblProducts (tsin)
- tblThresholds (offerId)

I'm trying to do a select on columns from all 3 tables.
The thing is, there might not be a record in `tblThresholds` which matches an `offerId`. In that instance, I still need the information from the other two tables to return... I don't mind if those columns or fields that are missing are null or whatever in the response.
Currently, I'm not getting anything back at all unless there is information in `tblThresholds` which correctly matches the `offerId`.

I suspect the issue lies with the way I'm doing the joining but I'm not very experienced with SQL and brand new to SQLAlchemy.
(Using MySQL by the way)

```
query = db.select([
    tblOffers.c.title,
    tblOffers.c.currentPrice,
    tblOffers.c.rrp,
    tblOffers.c.offerId,
    tblOffers.c.gtin,
    tblOffers.c.status,
    tblOffers.c.mpBarcode,
    tblThresholds.c.minPrice,
    tblThresholds.c.maxPrice,
    tblThresholds.c.increment,
    tblProducts.c.currentSellerId,
    tblProducts.c.brand,
    tblOffers.c.productTakealotURL,
    tblOffers.c.productLineId
]).select_from(
    tblOffers.
    join(tblProducts, tblProducts.c.tsin == tblOffers.c.tsinId).
    join(tblThresholds, tblThresholds.c.offerId == tblOffers.c.offerId)
)
```

I'm happy to add to this question or provide more information but since I'm pretty new to this, I don't entirely know what other information might be needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try for hours -> ask here -> find the answer minutes later on your own ‍♂️

So for those who might end up here for the same reason I did, here you go.

Turns out SQLAlchemy does a right join by default (from what I can tell - ***please correct me if I'm wrong***). I added a `isouter=True` to my join on `tblThresholds` and it worked!

Link to the info in the docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=join#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join.params.isouter

Final code:

```
query = db.select([
    tblOffers.c.title,
    tblOffers.c.currentPrice,
    tblOffers.c.rrp,
    tblOffers.c.offerId,
    tblOffers.c.gtin,
    tblOffers.c.status,
    tblOffers.c.mpBarcode,
    tblThresholds.c.minPrice,
    tblThresholds.c.maxPrice,
    tblThresholds.c.increment,
    tblProducts.c.brand,
    tblOffers.c.productTakealotURL,
    tblOffers.c.productLineId
]).select_from(
    tblOffers.
    join(tblProducts, tblProducts.c.tsin == tblOffers.c.tsinId).
    join(tblThresholds, tblThresholds.c.offerId == tblOffers.c.offerId, isouter=True)
)
```